# extract boundary from numerical integration by matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

If I have a numerical vector and I know the value of the integration of this vector in certain boundaries: How I can extract the boundary from the integration?

For example, I have `A=[4 5 6 9 8]` and `B=[1 3 2 5 6 3 5 8 10]` and I have this equation:

```
int(A)(from x1_1= ? to x1_2= ?)/int(A)(from x1_1=1 to x1_end=7) = 

      int(B)(from x2_1=2 to x2_2=3)/int(B)(from x2_1=2 to x2_end=9)
```

I know the right side of the integral - how can I get the boundary of the left-hand side integration?
I use `trapz` function to do the integral in matlab.

Comment: It feels like this is a question about numerical integration, not Matlab or programming.

Comment: yes but i want use matlab to solve problem

Comment: Will your problem always look like that? In that case, your data seems to be "small" enough that you could brute-force it. But: Have you considered that there may be more than one pair of `x1_1,x1_2` that satisfy your equation?

Comment: does not matter yes may there is but i want collect all boundary satisfy the equation

Answer (score 0):

Once you do the three integrals with known boundaries, your problem reduces to:

```
int(A)(from x1_1= ? to x1_2= ?) = constant
```

Since A is positive definite, and only defined over a limited range, you should be able to do this easily.  Also note that both A and B consist of a few straight line segments, so you should be able to do this all by hand, without Matlab.  You are making this too hard.

Comment: "*you should be able to do this easily*" - isn't this exactly what the OP wanted to know though? Can elaborate your answer a little more, please?

Comment: I have 209 items mattrix for A and 1801 for B i just gave example to make it esay
and the boundary of upper integral is change every iteration sequentially but lower integral is both whole boundary